# How to fields to date format in laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to convert the 2 fields into date using DB::raw and DATE_FORMAT in mysql but I'm getting null result. Please see my code below.

**Code**

```
$company = Company::select([
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT('1 ', month, ', ', year), '%M %d %Y') as date")
    ])
    ->limit(2)
    ->get();
```

**Result**

```
[
    {
        "date": null
    },
    {
        "date": null
    }
]
```

**Data stored in db**

```
+-----------------+
| month    | year |
+-----------------+
| January  | 2021 |
+-----------------+
| March    | 2021 |
+-----------------+
| February | 2022 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: What format are you looking for? "January, 2021" or "01-2021"  or other?

Comment: @john_ch "01-01-2021"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `STR_TO_DATE` to generate date then format using `DATE_FORMAT`

```
$company = Company::selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1',month,year),'%d%M%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') as date")
->limit(2)
->get();
```

Here `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1',month,year),'%d%M%Y')` will generate MySQL formated date like `2021-01-01`

Ref:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Ref:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format